# Future Object with mentioned timeOut is keep increasing for the next threads(timeOut is not applying for all the threads in the ThreadPool in Java)

Tags: java, timeout, java-7, future, executorservice

The Worker Thread is Defined here with heavy task of 10 Seconds in run method

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class WorkerThread implements Callable {

private String command;
private long startTime;
public WorkerThread(String s){
    this.command=s;
}

@Override
public Object call() throws Exception {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(new Date()+"::::"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Start. Command = "+command);
    Random generator = new Random(); 
    Integer randomNumber = generator.nextInt(5); 
    processCommand();
    System.out.println(new Date()+ ":::"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" End.::"+command+"::"+ (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));
    return randomNumber+"::"+this.command;
}

private void processCommand() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Interrupted::;Process Command:::"+this.command);
    }
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return this.command;
}

}
```

Defined my WorkerPool with the Future get Timeout of 1 second.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
public class WorkerPool {

        static BlockingQueue queue=new LinkedBlockingQueue(2);
        static RejectedExecutionHandlerImpl rejectionHandler = new RejectedExecutionHandlerImpl();
        static ThreadFactory threadFactory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();
        static ThreadPoolExecutor executorPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4, 4, 11, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue, threadFactory, rejectionHandler);
        static MyMonitorThread monitor = new MyMonitorThread(executorPool, 3);
        public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException{
            List<Future<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Future<Integer>>();
            for(int i=1; i< 5; i++){
                WorkerThread worker = new WorkerThread("WorkerThread:::_"+i);
                Future<Integer> future = executorPool.submit(worker);
                list.add(future);
            }

            for(Future<Integer> future : list){
                try {
                    try {
                        future.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                        future.cancel(true);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            executorPool.shutdown();
        }

    }
```

The Timeout of the thread is keep incresaing for the future threads, My expectation should be that if all the threads are taking more than 1 Second should close all at a time with in the ! second.

In the aboce scenario, worker thread is taking 10 sec to process, But i m timing out all my 4 threads with in 1 Seconds , but each thread time increasing incrementaly by 1 second for each task.

first thred timeOut is 1 Second
second thred timeOut is 2 Second
third thred timeOut is 3 Second.

**Why all threads are not interupting in 1 Second itself?Any problem with my code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are waiting sequentially in a loop in this section:

```
for(Future<Integer> future : list) {
  ...
  future.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  ...
}
```

Basically the flow is:

```
 - all workers 1 .. 4 start
 - you wait for worker A to finish
 - 1 second passes, TimeoutException (worker A was alive for 1 second)
 - you wait for worker B to finish
 - 1 second passes, TimeoutException (worker B was alive for 2 seconds)
 - you wait for worker C to finish
 - 1 second passes, TimeoutException (worker C was alive for 3 seconds)
 - ... same for D ...
```

If you want to wait for at most 1 second for *all workers* you need to count how much time you spent waiting so far, and then wait for remaining time.
Something like the pseudocode:

```
long quota = 1000
for (Future future : futures) {
  long start = System.currentTimeMillis
  try {
    future.get(quota, MILLISECONDS)
  }
  catch (TimeoutException e) {
    future.cancel(true)
  }
  finally {
    long spent = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
    quota -= spent
    if (quota < 0) {quota = 0} // the whole block is going to execute longer than .get() only
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution works, only for corepool size and will not work if threads are in the queue

Comment: Why so complicated? Just define `long deadline = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;` before the loop. Then, just `future.get(Math.max(0, deadline - System.currentTimeMillis()), MILLISECONDS);` in the loop. Or, put all `Callable`s into a `List` and invoke [`executorPool.invokeAll(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)), to get the logic for free.